# There is no Add Method for created entity instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm new at C# and I want to add data to database but I can not find the Add Method. Check the codes below

```
exampleEntity entity = new exampleEntity();
for (i= 0; i < Int32.Parse(questionNo); i++) 
{
if (Request.Form["DropDownList0" + i] == null)
{

continue;
}  
else
{
dropdownResult = Request.Form["DropDownList0" + i];
dropDownSoruNo = Request.Form["questionNo" + i];
dbTable1 insert = new dbTable1();
insert.db_id = dbKey;
insert.dber_id = dberKey;
insert.question_id = Int32.Parse(checkBoxQuestionNo);
insert.answer = dropdownResult;
entity.!!!!!
 }
}
```

There is no Add or Addto Method available for entity Instance.

Comment: Where is your `DbContext`? You want to use that

Comment: which version of entity framework you are using

Comment: have you generate the entity using database or it is blank entity object

Comment: geedubb, can you explain that what do you mean with DbContext, I'm not familiar to C# terms.
Nilesh I use database here is the my database schema image link = imageshack[dat]com/a/img839/1286/5ay.png

Comment: take a look at http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/create-dbcontext.aspx

Comment: By the way, dbTable1 is anketkayit in database I just translated it  in English to mae you understand.

Comment: Nilesh I created DbContext, what should I do now ? Still there is no Add Method available

Comment: can you show us what have you done so far...

Comment: This is my code behind : http://codepaste.net/iko4tf
This is database schema related with project : http://imageshack.com/a/img839/1286/5ay.png
This is the preview of the project on browser : http://imageshack.com/a/img839/6624/szte.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*C# is no big deal language, If you comfortable with a object oriented language. that is enough to work in c#. Please try out the following links, these may helpful for you to proceed further.*

[MSDN Entity Framework Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738561%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Entity Framework Sample](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/save-entity-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Hope these links will help you.